# Grouping by multiple columns and then projecting

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

In the below code I am trying to return a new sequence type that is grouped by the ProductName, Size, and Packaging properties from the original sequence, but instead I get a new type sequence that is ungrouped. What am I missing here?

```
query{
        for row in allDeliveries do
        let key = AnonymousObject<_,_,_>(row.ProductName,row.Size,row.Packaging)
        groupValBy row key into g
        select g
    }
    |> Seq.map (fun (del) -> 
    {
        POFD = del;
        ProductName = del.Key.Item1;
        Size = del.Key.Item2;
        Packaging = del.Key.Item3;
        Quantity = del.Count()
    })
```

Comment: I don't think that `AnonymousObject` will implement some kind of equivalence check - why don't you use a normal F# tuple like `groupValBy row (row.ProductName, row.Size, row.Packaging)`? And why don't you use the `select` part to get your record directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
query{
        for row in allDeliveries do
        groupValBy row (row.ProductName, row.Size, row.Packaging) into g
        select {
            POFD = g;
            ProductName = query{
                for row2 in g do
                select row2.ProductName
                headOrDefault
            }

            Size = query{
                for row2 in g do
                select row2.Size
                headOrDefault
            }
            Packaging = query{
                for row2 in g do
                select row2.Packaging
                headOrDefault
            }
            Quantity = g.Count()
        }
    }
```

Comment: see ... tuples did it for you ;)

Comment: @CarstenK&#246;nig yeah u should of posted it as an answer, :-)

Comment: nah it's fine ... I hope you get some Rep if you accept your own ... have some +1 ;)